# Statistical test for two-factor heteregeneously distributed samples

Tags: data-transformation, t-test, density-function, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

**Data**

I have a sample size of 50  in group A and 50 in group B where groups A and B are unmatched. Each sample in group A and group B has two frequencies associated with it, which I'll call $x$ and $y$.

A histogram of $x_{A}$ shows that it is clearly Gaussian and a Shapiro test confirms this. However, the distribution of $x_{B}$ is - according to a Shapiro test - not Gaussian (p<0.01).

For $y$, the distributions of group A and of group B are clearly not Gaussian but both have more of a Gamma-like or Weibull distribution (not sure which or whether it matters).

**Objective**

I want to be able to say whether any difference in $x_{A}$ and $x_{B}$ (as determined by some test statistic) is more significant (lower p-value) than any difference between $y_{A}$ and $y_{B}$.

**Thoughts**

Ideally, in order to make the p value from test with $x$ and the p value from test with $y$ comparable, I would think that the same statistical test would be needed. I know that when the spreads/distributions of $x_{A}$ and $x_{B}$ (and similarly for $y$ are the same, I can use the Mann Whitney test. However, the spreads (as described above are not the same). Therefore, could I do some sort of data transformation and do a t-test, or should I use a 2-sample Kolmogorov Smirnov test? In the latter case, how can I extend it to the *k*-sample case?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "more associated"? Once you answer that, you may know the answer yourself (sounds like you have knowledge of several tests), or someone else here may be able to help.

Comment: @PeterFlom I've cleared the question up a bit and tried to clarify my objective.